# Divs next to each other, 1: 200px, 2: 100%

Tags: html, css

i'm having a problem with divs.

I've been searching but couldn't get a solution.

I have 2 divs in a header. One containing logo and other contanining other things. First is 210px width and the second is 100% width (Fill available space).

I want to have the two on the same line.

I've been trying playing with display: inline, inline block, float left, but not working, second div is taking 100% of page and displaying below logo div.

Thanks in advance.

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/ukDQS/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need most of that junk.  It's pretty easy.  You're over thinking the problem.

First, a div is 100% by default, so you don't need to have the 100% on it.  Second, you just need to float the logo left, and assign a width to that.  That's all there is to it.  Get rid of all the display and other float and other kinds of positioning elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/QYftP/

Comment: THanks I don't understand why second div fills all the header... I suppose that it's because first one is floating in the air (?). I added margin-left to second div and now it is ok. Thanks

Comment: I've found utility in overflow:hidden instead of margin

Answer (score 1):

Follow the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ukDQS/3/

div#header-right-content { div.logo }

Answer (score 1):

```
#logo {
    float: left;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    width: 210px;
}
#header-right-content {
    height: 80px;
    margin-left: 210px;
    position: relative;
}
```

You don't need to set width 100% to the second div, because it'll expand to the fullr est of space.